Non-reflexive use of laisser without a direct object in « The Stranger » ?
I'm reading The Stranger in French and encountered this sentence, whose grammar confused me:

Mais le passage des nuées avait laissé sur la rue comme une promesse de pluie qui l'a rendue plus sombre.

Laisser QUOI? Shouldn't this either be se laisser or else have a direct object? I had to look up an English version of the book to understand this sentence, and even seeing its translation - "But the passing clouds had left a hint of rain hanging over the street, which made it look darker" - I still don't understand its grammar.
Edit: Now that I read it again for the 15th time, I see maybe de pluie is the D.O. ? Is it like "The passage of the clouds had left on the road (like a promise) rain which made it darker" ? I had been reading it as "The passage of the clouds had left on the road (like a promise of rain) which made it darker."

Compare to English I’m so hungry. I could eat like a whole apple pie, where like doesn’t introduce a manner of eating, but rather qualifies  the estimate of the intensity of the speaker’s hunger.

There is a DO. Except it's introduced by comme.

The DO is "comme une promesse de pluie"; I would translate as The passing clouds had sort of darkened the street with the promise of more rain.

Nice question since if you haven't seen this, it certainly is somewhat garden-pathy, as if one had omis une virgule : "Had left, like a promise of rain, [object please??] that darkened it" or "Had left, like a promise, de [la??] pluie that had darkened it."

Devant un substantif, un adjectif qualificatif ou un participe. 'comme' marque l'approximation, l'analogie. (Before a noun, an adjective, a past participle or a gerund. 'comme' marks the approximation, the analogy*).
Synonymes : En quelque sorte, pour ainsi dire, quasi.

Il eut comme une révélation.
Il entendit comme un coup de tonnerre.
J'ai vu comme une ombre traverser la cour.
C'était comme un retour à son enfance.
Nous l'avons vu comme fou d'épouvante.
Elle restait là, comme frappée par la foudre.

Source: Cntrl

Indeed: "Something like a promise of rain (to come)."

Okay, so I should basically read this as though the comme were not there to get the general meaning of the sentence. It is basically the same. And then the comme is a modifier that changes it from "a promise of rain" to "something like a promise of rain." Have I got that right? Just as Luke said in a comment, it is very much similar to like in English.

@temporary_user_name : that's right, "comme" is a modifier that can be omitted in all examples and may be translated by "something like" (when preceding a noun) or "somehow.".

Oui, pluie est le C.O.D., plus exactement promesse de pluie, car la pluie n'est pas arrivée jusqu’au sol et est restée dans les nuages.
D'un point de vue grammatical on peut analyser les divers groupes de mots de la phrase ainsi :

Le passage des nuées : Sujet de avait laissé

avait laissé : Verbe de la principale

sur la rue : Complément Circonstanciel (lieu)

comme une promesse de pluie : C.O.D. de avait laissé

qui : pronom relatif, représentant promesse de pluie, Sujet de a rendue

l' : pronom personnel représentant la rue, C.O.D de a rendue.

a rendue : verbe de la subordonnée

plus sombre : groupe adjectival, attribut de rue


